# Sending cookie with http post android

Tags: android, http, zend-framework, post, cookies

Hello guys I'm trying to send a cookie with http post in android

here's my code

```
webUrl = "XXXXXX";
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        try
        {
            CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
            Cookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("session_id", "1234");
            cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            BasicHttpContext mHttpContext = new BasicHttpContext();

            mHttpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

             HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("XXXXX");

             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

             Log.i("TAG", "Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
             if (entity != null) {
                 entity.consumeContent();
             }
             Log.i("TAG", "Initial set of cookies:");
             List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
             if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                 Log.i("TAG", "None");
             } else {
                 for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                     Log.i("TAG", "- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                 }
             }

            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("XXXXX");

            List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("session_id", "1234"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("selected_cid", "1234"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("selected_kaisai_id", "1234"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("iid", "1234"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tid", "1234"));

            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));

            response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
            entity = response.getEntity();

            Log.i("TAG", "Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
            if (entity != null) {
                entity.consumeContent();
            }

            Log.i("TAG", "Post logon cookies:");
            cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                }
            }
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();        
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("TAG", e.getMessage());
        }
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String postData = "session_id=1234";
        webView.postUrl(webUrl, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
```

I can post the data from postData but not the cookie
the cookie isn't showed in the webview
here's the PHP side

```
public function cookietestAction()
    {
        echo "mixi for netrecorder tester<br/>\n";

        echo "<br/>Cookies...<br/>\n\n";
        $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
        $sessionid = $request->getCookie('session_id');
        echo "<br/>\nsessionid = ".$sessionid."<br/>\n";

        $selected_cid = $request->getCookie('selected_cid');
        echo "\nselected_cid = ".$selected_cid."<br/>\n";

        $selected_kaisai_id = $request->getCookie('selected_kaisai_id');
        echo "\nselected_kaisai_id = ".$selected_kaisai_id."<br/>\n";

        $iid = $request->getCookie('iid');
        echo "\niid = ".$iid."<br/>\n";

        $tid = $request->getCookie('tid');
        echo "\ntid = ".$tid."<br/>\n";

        if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
        {
            echo "<br/>POST data only...<br/>\n\n";
            $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost('session_id');
            echo "<br/>\nsession_id=".$post."<br/>\n";
            $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selected_cid');
            echo "selected_cid=".$post."<br/>\n";
            $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selected_kaisai_id');
            echo "selected_kaisai_id=".$post."<br/>\n";
            $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost('tid');
            echo "tid=".$post."<br/>\n";
            $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost('iid');
            echo "iid=".$post."<br/>\n";
        }
}
```

can anyone tell me what's wrong?
thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

to add cokie use it like this: it should be added in header

```
        post.addHeader("Cookie", " PHPSESSID="+PHPSESSID+"; gc_userid="+gc_user+"; gc_session="+gc);
```

for you it should be like:

```
     httpost.addHeader("Cookie","session_id = 1234;"...)
```

Comment: sorry droidhot,but it didn't work,do I need to add more code?
thanks

Comment: Now, *that* looks better. Your initial code was just setting a header - not a *cookie* header.

Comment: yap actually my server wanted both so i misplaced it with the other

Comment: I'm sorry still not working,is there anything wrong with my code?
it's working in the iphone but in the android it didn't work,but the logic is different

Comment: this has to be changed as per your server  " PHPSESSID="+PHPSESSID+"; gc_userid="+gc_user+"; gc_session="+gc

Comment: Yes I've changed it into  httpost.addHeader("Cookie","session_id = 1234;") but i didn't send all the cookie value because this is only for testing,maybe because of that?I'll try it later and inform you,thanks for your help

Comment: I'm finally found a solution using this 
 CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this); 
      CookieManager cookieManager =  CookieManager.getInstance(); 
      
      String getcookie =  cookieManager.getCookie(webUrl); 
      
      cookieManager.setCookie(webUrl, "session_id="+id); 
      cookieManager.setCookie(webUrl, "selected_cid="+id); 
      cookieManager.setCookie(webUrl, "selected_kaisai_id="+id); 
      cookieManager.setCookie(webUrl, "iid="+id); 
      cookieManager.setCookie(webUrl, "tid="+id);
but I'll mark @droidhot answer OK,thanks for the help droidhot!

Comment: @nayoso: Why did you do a `getCookie` in that?